# compile/install gcc 4.1.2 on solaris 10 having gcc 3.4.3 already

Tags: unix, gcc, posix, solaris, solaris-10

I'm facing some issues on compiling gcc on solaris 10.

I downloaded the source code from "ftp://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/gcc/releases/gcc-4.1.2/" and tried to compile it, by using configure and then make.
But the make stops at line mentioned below.

> perl ../.././fastjar/../contrib/texi2pod.pl -D fastjar  > fastjar.pod

I'hv checked perl is already installed but it has stuck at this point for more than 12hrs.

gcc version already installed is 3.4.3
perl version is 5.8.4

---

The above problem is solved as i used ksh shell to build/configure it, but i ran into another problem i.e. the gcc which i got after this build says

> warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored

This visibility feature is required as i don't want to export all of my function in my shared libraries.
According to [this link](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46713) the waring is due to objdump which it says is not present in my $PATH. But i checked it is in $PATH variable.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to install such an old version of GCC? It's up to 4.7 now.

Comment: currently i'm porting a project from RHEL to solaris. So i want to get same environment in solaris as in RHEL.

Comment: solved by copying all gnutools in a seprate directory and added the path to path variable in begning. then compiling it. thankx Joachim Pileborg for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i solved this problem:

1. Installed gnu binutils version 2.18 using gcc 3.4.3(available in solaris by default).
2. cd gcc_source_dir
3. mkdir objdir && cd objdir
4. ../configure --with-gnu-as --with-as=/binutils_2_18/bin/as --with-gnu-ld --with-ld=/binutils_2_18/bin/ld --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-shared --disable-symvers --enable-languages=c,c++
5. gmake
6. gmake install

Comment: The binutils supplied with solaris is having some bugs. So better to upgrade it before using.